# Lagging on HTML5 videos using AMD proprietary drivers

Tags: 14.04, ati, steam

I've been using Ubuntu for about 2 years from now for all my tasks, including software development and deploy.

Lately, I decided to try some games on it, starting for `Dota 2` from Steam. At that moment, i was using open-source drivers, which is included with Ubuntu 14.04.

I read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) to install AMD proprietary drivers, including Catalyst Control Center. My graphic card is a **AMD Radeon R7 M265** (dual graphics with an Intel Graphics Card, don't know the model exactly). I followed all the steps they provide, rebooted my system and tried launch the game.

Everything works fine inside the game (even better than Windows 8.1, my last OS), achieving a performance of up to 70 fps, but when I opened the browser to watch some videos on Youtube and put them on fullscreen, the video is lagging, seems like it's on **5~6 fps**.

Looking in AMD Catalyst Control Center, I found an option to change the GPU and when I choose **Intel GPU**, the problem seems to fade, the video is playing without lag, but inside the game it doesn't have the same performance.

Has anyone gone through this same problem? Is there a bug on AMD graphics driver or some configuration I have to do on Catalyst Center?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**PS**: I'm using Google Chrome - Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit), but the problem is also reproducing in Firefox 45.0